# Sort top 10 elements from an array using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, nspredicate

Can anyone tell me how to use `NSPredicate` to select top 10 items from an array based on some conditions,such as top 10 viewed films?Like the sql statement:

```
select * from films where film.views limit 10;
```

Comment: No, no one can. NSPredicate doesn't do `limit`.

Comment: Do you have any specific reason why it has to be done using `NSPredicate`?

Comment: Is it really from a NSArray? Or are you performing a CoreData fetch, in which case you sort sort and use a `fetchLimit`.